# HiveException when running a sql example in Spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

a newbie in apache spark here! I am using Spark 2.4.0 and Scala version 2.11.12, and I'm trying to run the following code in my spark shell -

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spark.implicits._
var df = spark.read.json("storesales.json")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("storesales")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM storesales")
```

And I get the following error -

```
2018-12-18 07:05:03 WARN  Hive:168 - Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.
hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java
:62)
```

I also saw this [Issues trying out example in Spark-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088433/issues-trying-out-example-in-spark-shell) and as per the accepted answer, I have tried to start my spark shell like so,
`~/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file:///tmp/spark-warehouse`, however, it did not help and the issue persists.

Comment: Are you able to start Hive using CLI ?

Comment: Did you try with double (not triple) slash in the file  `spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file://tmp/spark-warehouse`